# Assign default role when new user register - drupal 8

Tags: drupal, module, webforms

I’m trying to assign default role for all new register user. but I got

```
Error: Call to a member function addRole() on array in my_module_user_insert()
```

my code is

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
unset($form['account']['mail']['#description']);
unset($form['account']['name']['#description']);
unset($form['account']['pass']['#description']);
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'my_module_user_insert';
}  
}
function my_module_user_insert($entity) {
  $entity->addRole('newcompanies'); 
  $entity->save();
}
```

I try to use Administrator role in account settings [admin/config/people/accounts] page but not working. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your custom module:

```
use Drupal\user\UserInterface;

function my_module_user_insert(UserInterface $user) {
    $rid = array_search('newcompanies', user_roles());

    $user->addRole($rid);
    $user->save();
}
```

**Explanation**: You have to hook into the `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert`, and then add the desired role for the user being created. Note you have to add the role id instead of the role name!

I haven't tried it, just wrote it by memory, hope it helps!